# How to keep auto wrap in editText, but disable word wrap?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Question is when the text in editText is too long, and in the end of the line, the auto wrap will do the word wrap, like this:

```
|                    |
|https://www.google. |
|com.hk/             |
|webhp?sourceid=chrom|
|e-instant           |
```

> Anyone knows how to prevent word wrap? I'd like to have result like this:

```
|                    |
|https://www.google.c|
|om.hk/webhp?sourceid|
|=chrome-instant     |
|                    |
```

Here is XML for reference:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/passbook_form_item_value"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
android:background="@null"
android:textColor="@color/dark_3"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
```

Comment: While Editing the text?

Comment: Use  android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" in your xml for EditText

Comment: you need to add to EditText (android:singleLine="true" & 
    android:lines="1")

Comment: Yes, while editing the text

Comment: And want to keep the editText multi line

Comment: have you figured out how to do this yet?